What is the biblical concept/idea/meaning of Gods omniscience?
I have rewritten my question a few times because I had difficulties dealing with the definition of omniscience. Originally I wanted to know the difference between the concept of omniscience from a logical point of view with the view of the bible.
However, I noticed that defining omniscience from a logical or philosophical point of view, although interesting, is quite a bag of worms, that I might open with a different question though. I know this could make the question difficult to answer as one might respond with: "What do you mean with omniscience then?" to which I respond with: "That is exactly the question. What is omniscience according to the Bible?". To break the cycle though, we could go for the scope/limits of God's knowledge if that helps.
In this question, I am interested in the Biblical view/concept/meaning and limits of the omniscience of God. What can we actually conclude from the Bible on the nature of omniscience? In particular, I am most interested in the omniscience of God regarding the future (foreknowledge).
So for a focused phrasing of the question:

What is the concept/idea/meaning/nature of omniscience in the Bible?
Are there limits to this omniscience described in the Bible? If so which are they?
Maybe the question could also be: "What does the Bible say about the scope/limit of God's knowledge?"
If the word "omniscience" is not the word that represents the biblical position with adequate precision: What would be a better word?

So a few Verses that I came across when researching omniscience in the Bible:
Hebrews 4:13

And no creature is hidden from his sight, but all are naked and exposed to the eyes of him to whom we must give account.

From Hebrews, I can conclude that God is seeing/is aware of every creature. The "exposed" part is a bit more abstract for me, but I think it points to the idea that humans cannot deceive God by lying or omitting information.
What I cannot conclude from Hebrews yet is a total omniscience, since it does not say anything about past/future or possibilities.
1 John 3:20

for whenever our heart condemns us, God is greater than our heart, and he knows everything.

So either omniscience in 1. John is focused on our heart here, meaning our inner thoughts, emotions, unconscious thoughts, and attitudes, and I would even go for other factors, like hormones. Or "everything" is referring to literally everything.
Isaiah 46:10

I make known the end from the beginning, from ancient times, what is still to come. I say, “My purpose will stand, and I will do all that I please.”

From Isaiah, I drew the conclusion that God knows everything that happened in the past but more importantly, what will happen in the future.
Matthew 10:29-30

Are not two sparrows sold for a penny?[9] And not one of them will fall to the ground apart from your Father.
30 But even the hairs of your head are all numbered.

The omniscience in Matthew seems to be similar to the one in Hebrews, basically saying that God knows everything that is going on physically.
Edit added Bible passages (Thank you @Mark Vestal)
1 Peter 1:2

"Elect according to the foreknowledge of God the Father, through
sanctification of the Spirit, unto obedience and sprinkling of the
blood of Jesus Christ: Grace unto you, and peace, be multiplied."

=> Here I can only conclude that God has some foreknowledge, but it's not clear to what extent. Or at least I am not sure how "Elect according" impacts the scope of Gods foreknowledge.
Acts 2:22-23

22 Ye men of Israel, hear these words; Jesus of Nazareth, a man approved of God among you by miracles and wonders and signs, which God did by him in the midst of you, as ye yourselves also know: Him, being delivered by the determinate counsel and foreknowledge of God, ye have taken, and by wicked hands have crucified and slain:

=> This passage is focused on Jesus and the foreknowledge of God regarding it. The question here is though if that was God's foreknowledge or plan.
Are there verses that I missed?
In Reference to the previous questions:

How do Christians reconcile God's omnipotence with his omniscience? The Answers here are focusing a lot on omnipotence instead of omniscience.
What is the biblical evidence for God's omnipotence and omniscience? Here there are more biblical passages quotes for omniscience. However, I am asking for a biblical-based description of omniscience.
What is meant by "God is Omnipotent"? features a great answer regarding omnipotence compared to the term "almighty". This answer might have implications for omniscience, but it is still focused on omnipotence nevertheless.
Why make an effort to get saved if my life is pre destined by God? While the description of Matthew (Author of the top answer) of God being beyond time might work intuitively I am again more interested in the biblical view/basis of it.
Which verses in the Bible say that God is omniscient? Another great answer for more passages. However, it also features a defence against Open Theism that includes a lot of scripture, which comes to the conclusion that God has "exhaustive knowledge of the future".

Differences in denominations:
Just to make sure that this factor does not close this question as I don't know if there are denominational differences that are significant enough to warrant a closing of the question:
The question focuses specifically on what can be concluded from the Bible. I even made the mistake of opening the question on Biblical-Hermeneutics.SE because of that focus. But I will always cherish the perspective of any denomination, so if there are differences I am interested in reading about them.

The word 'omniscience' occurs nowhere in the Bible. The word was coined centuries after the last book of the Bible was completed. The fact that it has 'science' in it is the Big Clue. If that word had been invented in the days of Augustine, he might have replaced 'natural philosophy' with it. So, the Bible itself does not categorize God as being omniscient. You helpfully quote 6 Bible texts that form a basis for the answer to your question. There are more, of course. Collating all of them would complete the answer.

Omniscience simply means that God knows everything. More precisely, we could say that everything that can be known is known by God. (So he doesn't need to know paradoxes or logical contradictions, like what a four sided triangle looks like, or how to cook a burrito too hot for even himself to eat it.)
Note that this definition punts the question of knowing the future: if the future can't be known, then it doesn't negate God's omniscience. So while the great majority of Christians do think God knows not just all the possible futures but which possible future will actually happen, even those who believe God doesn't know which future will happen could still say that God has omniscience. No doubt there are some Christians who truly do deny the omniscience of God (beyond saying he doesn't know the unknowable, including the future), but they are quite rare, and I'm not aware of any denominations that officially deny it.

Thank you for your answer. Do you follow that God cannot know the non-sensical from C.S. Lewis on omnipotence (God cannot do the logical impossible)? Also  "if the future can't be known," aren't there passages indicating that the future can be known based on prophecies e.g.?

Yea the non-sensical is like the paradoxes or logical contradictions I mentioned in the first paragraph. Well I do agree the Bible teaches that God does know the future. I don't know how open theists etc can rationalise it otherwise.

Oh, I think Open Theists make a big difference in knowing some future, having the power to determine specific future events (like the birth of Jesus), and having a complete exhaustive knowledge of the future. So Open Theists do think the future can be known but not "everything".
